# If the set defined by a homogeneous polynomial is simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If $f$ is a irreducible homogeneous polynomial over field $\mathbb{C}$ with degree $n$, we consider set $f=1$, which is a topological space,it's topology is induced by the normal topology of $\mathbb{C}^{N}$,where $N$ is the number of parameters in $f=1$.  I wonder if it is a simply connected space, as we have example $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is simply connected.

Comment: It is "simply connected" not "simple connected."

Comment: oh,sorry,I will edit it.

Comment: You corrected one out of three. The rest is still poorly written since you did not specify the ambient space where you are solving the equation $f=1$. You also probably forgot the irreducibility condition.

Answer (score 4):

No. For example the set $\{ xy = 1 \} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ is not simply connected; it is the punctured complex plane $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ so it has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible?

Comment: @ckx $xy-1 = 1$ then